# How do I read the content of a HttpResponseMessage while preserving the original response?

Tags: c#, http

Given some HttpResponseMessage response, if I call

```
await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(),
```

I run into issues down the road, presumably due to the content being readable only once. I've also tried:

```
var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStream();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

But HttpBaseStream does not support Seek.

Context is that I want to implement a DelegatingHandler that replaces the response for base.SendAsync only under specific circumstances (that I can only establish by reading the content of the base response). Is there maybe a totally different, more appropriate way to achieve that?

Comment: `ReadAsStream` does not consume the content of `response.Content` - it just returns a readable stream representation from the start of the response-so-far - so calling `.Seek` immediately afterwards is a NOOP. Instead, create a new Stream to buffer the response (such as a `MemoryStream` or writable `FileStream` to copy `response.Stream` into, _then_ you rewind the buffer stream. Don't forget to rewind it after each time you read from it.

Comment: I just tried:
response.Content.CopyTo(ms, null, CancellationToken.None);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
but I get "InvalidOperationException(SR.net_http_content_stream_already_read)"

Comment: Show us your code that covers the entire lifespan of your `HttpResponseMessage`.